# Cannot stop a trace file after boot, because the filename changes every time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am using this .cmd file, that stops should stop a file.
After rebooting the name of the file changes according to date and time.
Is there a way to update the name in the cmd file?
Or rename it as the cmd file before the cmd file runs?
To run the cmd file, I use task scheduler to run at boot.

```
@echo off
NSudoLC -U:T -P:E logman stop -n UserNotPresentTraceSession -ets
NSudoLC -U:T -P:E logman stop -n SHS-05042023-230640-7-7f -ets
```

When I edit the cmd script, the file is named `SHS-05092023-070344-7-7f`
but after reboot it gets renamed by adding date and time.

THIS IS WHAT AM TRYING TO DO.
ill try to explain a bit more.. maybe i wasnt clear.
i have this cmd file that runs on every boot so that it stops the trace when i create and run the file for the first time it works because the file name is the same
example: SHS-05042023-230640-7-7f its the file name and its the same at the cmd file. so far so good. but on a reboot that file SHS-05042023-230640-7-7f
is created but different date and time (05042023-230640) so the cmd file cant stop it because its no longer the same file name in the OS.

is there a way to either

1. OS boot creates new file SHS-050102023-230640-7-7f before the cmd file runs is there a way to renamed created file back to what its on the cmd file that way it stops it.?
   or let it create a new file with date and time and before the cmd file runs have the cmd file change the file name in there to the created one so that way it stops it.?
   i hopw i made my self clear. english isnt my first language. and i admit sometimes what i write dont make sense..
   thank you

Comment: Are you expecting to magically determine the exact date and time that the file was renamed shortly after the system and OS software was rebooted? If so then it cannot be done. The only alternative would be to know the location and a specific unique filename pattern, get that filename, then use it. If there can be multiple similarly named files the you'd need to determine the file by its modified or created date and time stamp, (if it isn't simply renamed), or by parsing the filename substring, converting that to a date object, and comparing it against the others. Anyhow, this is all off topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @compo i have 0 knowledge am asking if its possible or alternative .  either a way to rename the file example it starts and createst file based on date and time. so maybe a way to then rename it back to what i have in the code.. or a way to change the code and copy the new name created upon boot. hopw i make sense english isnt my language. thanks